# n'th biggest number in a multi-dimensional list in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Imagine I have a 2D list of numbers in Mathematica :

```
myList = Table[{i,i*j},{i,1,10},{j,1,10}];
```

and I want to retrieve the 5th highest values in an efficient way. Using RankedMax gives an error. For example,

```
Max[myList]
```

gives 100 but:

```
RankedMax[myList,1]
```

gives :

```
 RankedMax::vec :  "Input {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, \

{1, 7}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {1, 10}}, {{2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 6}, {2, 8}, {2, 10}, \

{2, 12}, {2, 14}, {2, 16}, {2, 18}, {2, 20}}, 6, {{9, 9}, {9, 18}, {9, 27}, \

{9, 36}, {9, 45}, {9, 54}, {9, 63}, {9, 72}, {9, 81}, {9, 90}}, {{10, 10}, \

{10, 20}, {10, 30}, {10, 40}, {10, 50}, {10, 60}, {10, 70}, {10, 80}, {10, \

90}, {10, 100}}} is not a vector
```

How do I use RankedMax on my data or is there any other way around ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Flatten

```
RankedMax[Flatten@myList,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fine if he's just looking for the fifth biggest of all the numbers in the table. If, as I suspect, he's looking for the fifth biggest of the calculated terms -- the second element in each pair -- we should slightly amend the previous solution to read:

```
RankedMax[Flatten@Map[Rest, myList, {2}], 5]
```